# A tiny plain Java EE 7 fails on dependency injection

Tags: java, servlets, dependency-injection, java-ee-7

I have a very small Java EE 7 web application:

**`MyServlet.java`:**

```
@WebServlet(name="MyServlet", urlPatterns={"/getData"})
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
   
    @Inject private DataProvider dataProvider;
    
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
                          HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.getWriter().println(dataProvider.getSome());
    }
}
```

**`DataProvider.java`:**

```
public interface DataProvider {

    public String getSome();
}
```

**`DataProviderImpl.java`:**

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class DataProviderImpl implements DataProvider {
    
    public String getSome() {
        return "DATA";
    }
}
```

**Symptoms:** when I run the servlet (via a GET request), `MyServlet.dataProvider` is still `null`. What am I doing wrong here? I tried hard to find any information on idiomatic dependency injection usage, yet failed to get any helpful advise.

(I am running this on Apache Tomcat 9.0.30.)

Comment: Where are you running this tiny application?

Comment: @BoristheSpider Apache Tomcat 9.0.30.

Comment: Apache Tomcat is not a JavaEE application server. It’s a servlet container. It does not have a CDI framework. You’ll need to switch to an actual JavaEE application server - like TomEE; or add a container DI framework like Weld.